# Can't make a div fixed on the page

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I always wanted to be fixed on the top of the page but it doesn't seem to work.. here is the div code itself

```
  <div class="up-label">
    <p><span>Testing 123.</span><br>
      Blah BLah </p>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.up-label {
 position: fixed;
 top: 20px;
 left: 20px 
 /*
 width: auto;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-top:-6px;
 padding:10px; */
}
```

It seems to just stay where it's at but not fixed in the window.

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/DKAwn/

Comment: code works fine directly copied

Comment: Must be something else overriding the settings then.

Comment: can you post the full html code , that way it will easy to understand your issue .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are under IE6, IE6 don't surpport position:fixed,  use js to fix.

Comment: Making a fixed position polyfill in JS just to support IE6 is a bad idea. It would be better to fallback to position absolute in non-supporting browsers.

Comment: yes, but when we have to achieve the same effect as position:fixed, js is the only solution.

Answer (score -1):

There doesnt seem to be any problem with the code. There might be some other problem, for e.x, it ur using a external css file, make sure its attatched properly to your html file. also try testing in diffrent browsers (google chrome, firefox, opera etc..) to make sure that its not the specific browser doesnt accept or doesnt understand the css ur using.